# Getting "CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context" when deploying MVC3 remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, razor

I know this error has been posted elsewhere, but the solutions provided don't work for me.

Background:

- I created a brand new project using MVC3 with Razor syntax using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
- Everything works fine when I run the project locally.
- I installed MVC3 on my remote server and deployed the project.

I get the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
Source Error:
Line 1:  @model MyModels.AModel
Line 2:  @{
Line 3:      ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Line 4:  }
Line 5:  <script type="text/javascript">
```

- I checked, and I do have a Web.Config file in my Views directory that appears to be complete.
- This is not an upgraded solution. I did not go from a previous MVC beta to the final release.
- I'm going crazy at this point. I'll be happy to provide more information if requested.

Comment: Not too localized to keep mine or 2.2k other views from hitting this page intentionally in the past 5 months ;)

Answer (score 7):

Argh. The server where I had deployed my app to had an old version of MVC3. I **had** ran the MVC3 installer prior to deploying my app, but apparently the installer does not remove previous beta or RC versions of MVC3. You **must** uninstall previous versions of MVC3 via add/remove programs prior to installing the newer version.

I was able to make this work in two ways:

1. Uninstall MVC3 completely from the server, then bin deploy the MVC3 dlls with my app.
2. After uninstalling MVC3 completely, install the latest version from http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3

Note: Restart IIS after any changes. (Recycling just the app pool would probably work, too.)

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem, make sure you have a valid web.config in your Views directory as the SO indicated in the question. Bin deploy worked for me without having to install MVC3 as Jim did.